# Not able to understand parent child communication

Tags: angular

As i know for parent child communication there are many decorators like @Input, @Output, @ViewChild and many other methods but while giving to answer to one of question i came across below thing and now i am not able to understand it

App.component.ts ( Parent)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ChildComponent } from './child.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  parentVariable = 'parentTesting'
  // constructor(private childComp: ChildComponent) {    // Giving error
  //   console.log(this.childComp)  
  // }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<h1>Parent</h1>
<child></child>
```

child.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class ChildComponent  {
  childVariable = 'childTesting'
  constructor(private appComp: AppComponent) {
    console.log(this.appComp)  // This is working
  }
}
```

In Child component in constructor i am getting AppComponents instance but if i am doing same thing in Appcomponent's constructor is giving me fatal error.

Can you please let me know logic behind this

Comment: Only a child component can inject its parent component. It doesn't work the other way around. You are trying to inject a child component i.e (`child.component`) into its parent (`app.component`) which won't work.

Comment: Have a look :https://therichpost.com/angular-8-child-routing-working-example/

Comment: Please read [Parent-Child component communication in angular](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)

Comment: as mentioned above, also if you need to pass data from child to parent you can use the @Output decorator (https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event)

Comment: That's interesting! I made a stackblitz based on your code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qa9r2e. In fact, you can set the parent variable from the child component!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a circular reference issue which gives `Can't resolve all parameters for ChildComponent: (?).` error.

This is why:

You are trying to construct **AppComponent**, so you call the *constructor*.

The constructor needs **ChildComponent** to be constructed first and then provided, therefore call now **ChildComponent's** *constructor*.

And **ChildComponent's** *constructor* needs **AppComponent**, the `(?)` param, which ***is not constructed yet***, waiting for this to finish.